# Add attribute name to configurable select option in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, select, configurable-product-options

By default, the drop-down box for configurable products displays 'Choose an option...'. I'd like to change this to 'Select {attribute label}'.

I found the code for this in:

```
vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\view\frontend\templates\product\view\type\options\
```

Here the following code can be added to change to the required value:

```
<option value=""><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Select ').strtolower($block->escapeHtml($_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getStoreLabel())) ?></option>
```

When the page initially loads this seems to work, however, once the page loads this value gets instantly replaced by 'Choose an Option...' which I found loads from here:

```
/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php
```

Where it appears like this:

```
'chooseText' => __('Choose an Option...'),
```

Any idea how to insert the attribute name here or stop this from overwriting the change I have already made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to change that text in below file,

```
magento/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js
```

In this file, you need to find _fillSelect method and see "chooseText" value.

> element.options[0].innerHTML = this.options.spConfig.chooseText

Replace with below code

> var attribute_lable =
>   this.options.spConfig.attributes[element.id.replace(/[a-z]*/,
>   '')]['label'];
>               element.options[0].innerHTML = this.options.spConfig.chooseText + attribute_lable;

Note: Don't forgets to override this file and remove cache & run static-content:deploy command.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! I can see that this replaced the default value with the attribute code. How can I modify this to show the attribute label instead?

Comment: Sorry, your answer is almost right but not quite what I need. Your code displays 'choose ring_size' with 'ring_size' being the code for the attribute but I would like to display the attribute label since it's different depending on the store view. Is that possible?

Comment: The attribute code is 'ring_size' but the label is 'Size'. I want other attributes to work in the same way to it's important to use the label and not the code/id.

Comment: Can you please check/try my updated answer! If it's correct, then please accept as a right answer.